# Multi select dropdown list in spring mvc separated by comma

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jstl

Nearer to this Requirement[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14322390/using-springmvc-formselect-to-bind-comma-separated-values-to-multiple-dropdown)

Dropdown list is populated using separate table: stateid, statename

when user click on submit button data is stored as : 2,5,8 (selected options id's)

```
 <form:select path="permit_states" multiple="multiple" class="multiselect col-md-4">
    <form:options items="${statesList}" />
 </form:select>
```

when user click on edit button, i want to show previous selected options as checked:
In jsp's using jstl functions and expression language how we can acheive?!

[User Click on Edit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rj0Wx.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Refer the [Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.9.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib-optionstag)

```
<form:select path="permit_states" multiple="multiple" 
     items="${statesList}" itemValue="stateId" itemLabel="stateName"
     class="multiselect col-md-4">

</form:select>
```

Comment: Add an explanation

Comment: As it stands right now, your answer has little value because the reader has to research on their on about why this might work. Please consider adding some explanation and/or references.